# Internal exaption on play sound in QMediaPlayer

Tags: windows, qt, exception, stack-overflow, media-player

When I try to execute "play" with loop on file that not exist, I got exaption "stack_overflow".
I use Qt 5.15.2 and windows 7

```
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("not_exist"));
    playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);

    QMediaPlayer *music = new QMediaPlayer();
    music->setPlaylist(playlist);
    music->play();
```

Can I catch this exception or maybe I can use another way to run sound in the loop to exclude this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the error signal of QMediaPlayer:

```cpp
connect(music, QOverload<QMediaPlayer::Error>::of(&QMediaPlayer::error),
    [music](QMediaPlayer::Error error){
    qDebug() << error << music->errorString();
});
```

Output:

```
QMediaPlayer::ResourceError "Could not open resource for reading."
```

Comment: But this code doesn't help me.
I can get errors and status from mediaStatusChanged, but I can't prevent stack_overflow and crashing my application

Comment: @klynxe If there is a stackoverflow then there is a bug, in Linux with gstreamer there is only a warning that signals the error from the backend and on the Qt side the error signal is thrown, I recommend you report it.